# Excel- How to find the count excluding invalid characters

Tags: excel

How to find the invalid records in a column in excel. Invalid records in my example is having special characters not blanks in the columns

E.g : in a column I am having dates from A1: A10 and in A5 & A6 I will have `&&&&` and `%%%%`, I want a formula where it should give me a count and result is 8 excluding these two special characters values.

```
1/1/2013
1/2/2013
1/3/2013
1/4/2013
&&&&&
%%%%%
1/7/2013
1/8/2013
1/9/2013
1/10/2013
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Tried using COUNTIFS function, but invalid result

Comment: Could you put the formula you were trying to use in your question?

Comment: Perhaps `COUNTA(A:A)-COUNT(A:A)` to get the count of invalid entries

Comment: =COUNTIFS(Q18:Q27,"")

Comment: @tigeravatar Yup, I had that in mind as well.

Comment: To get the count of valid entries (dates), it would just be `COUNT(A:A)`

Comment: I got it =COUNTIFS(Q18:Q27,"*"), but the question is how it is excluding dates and giving the result

Comment: If you use the simple `COUNT` it will only count numbers, dates are numbers also, symbols are not. It you did `=Count(ColumnYouHave)` it would return 8

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Q18:Q27,"*")` will count all the cells having text values in them. Use `COUNT()` as already suggested by the other comments.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will count all cells that don't equal &&&&& or %%%%% ***including*** blanks.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"<>&&&&&",A1:A10,"<>%%%%%")
```

This formula will count all cells that don't equal &&&&& or %%%%% ***excluding*** blanks.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(COUNT(A1:A10)-(COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>&&&&&")-COUNTIF(A1:A10,"<>%%%%%")))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bit too complicated IMO =P

Comment: Albeit this is a long ago answer, to add info as the responder didn't. The  '<>' means non-blank cells. You also can, as is in the COUNTIFS formula, add character you also don't want to count to the right of the <> in the double quotes.

So essentially, the first formula is *count all non-blank cells that also don't have &&&&& or %%%%%*

Comment: Hi @Miniman - thanks for adding additional info to my answer to help improve it.  One small change... I believe '<>' is technically "does not equal" rather than "non-blank".  The first formula will count blanks but the second formula won't.

Comment: Automate This, @Miniman [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772267/2752308); this non/poor-documented trick, however, counts ="" as non-empty

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz - Good to know... Thanks for the link/tip