# count how many times a name is listed in column "F" if column "H" is blank. in same row as name

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, countif

i am not getting the correct results, the name C.C.Rentals is listed in sheets "All P.O. INFO T1" column "F" 19 times. `=COUNTIF('ALL P.O. INFO T1'!F:F,A9)` this works but i need it to count IF sheets"All P.O. INFO T1" column "H" is blank. if not blank do not count it. I have tried this: `=IF('ALL P.O. INFO T1'!G2<>"""",COUNTIF('ALL P.O. INFO T1'!F:F,A9))` and still get 19. i should get 17 due to sheets"All P.O. INFO T1" column "H" has two cells not blank..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get countifs to select all non-blank cells in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772225/how-do-i-get-countifs-to-select-all-non-blank-cells-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me  `=COUNTIFS('ALL P.O. INFO T1'!F:F,A9,'ALL P.O. INFO T1'!H:H,"")`